# How to set Highcharts labels width to 50%

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I have a Highcharts' bar chart with long labels.
I would like to allow them to grow up to 50% of the width of the container.
But no matter what I would do, they are not growing to this width.

Here is an example:

https://jsfiddle.net/agex7m0o/1/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Historic World Population by Region'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_population">Wikipedia.org</a>'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Africa Long Name Long Name Long Name Long Name Long Name', 'America', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Oceania'],
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        labels: {
            overflow: 'justify'
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Population (millions)',
            align: 'high'
        },
        labels: {
            overflow: 'justify'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ' millions'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        x: -40,
        y: 80,
        floating: true,
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor:
            Highcharts.defaultOptions.legend.backgroundColor || '#FFFFFF',
        shadow: true
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Year 1800',
        data: [107, 31, 635, 203, 2]
    }, {
        name: 'Year 1900',
        data: [133, 156, 947, 408, 6]
    }, {
        name: 'Year 2000',
        data: [814, 841, 3714, 727, 31]
    }, {
        name: 'Year 2016',
        data: [1216, 1001, 4436, 738, 40]
    }]
});
```

As you can see, the width of the left side (with the labels) is clearly narrower than the chart side. The labels are wrapping already, but the left side is not growing.

Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You can play with the margin parameter by adding in your chart options:

```
 chart: {
    type: 'bar',
    margin: [50,10,50,400]
},
```

see exemple : [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bcpjrwfx/2/)

link to the API: [here](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.margin)

Comment: Thanks, but with margin, this size is static then. And I don't know how long the names will be in each case.

Answer (score 0):

In the below demo the chart yAxis width is set as 50% of the general chart container width. Is that a solution which you have been looking for?

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/z0vbcf5x/

```
events: {
  render() {
    let chart = this;

    if (chartForRender) {
      chartForRender = false;
      chart.update({
        chart: {
          marginLeft: chart.chartWidth / 2
        }
      }, true, false, false)
    }
    chartForRender = true;
  }
}
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render

Comment: Thanks, but it does not allow the contents to grow. It sets the width to 50% statically...

Comment: I would like to allow the label part to grow up to 50% of the width of the container, but only if there is a label requiring it. Without it - it should be as narrow as labels require it.

Comment: @Rob.Ak I am afraid that I don't understand your requirement. Could you explain it more precisely? Sharing an image (of what is wrong and what should be done) could help.